# how to solve this error in action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

i have a problem with action bar.
i am changing te color or action bar.
but there is an error .
i can't understand how to solve this.
this is the code of my java file.

LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,AllInOneAsyncTask.ServiceResultListener {

    private EditText loginUserId,loginPassword;
    private Button btnLogin;
    private TextView tvForgetPassword;
    private AppSharedPreference appSharedPreference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.header)));

        appSharedPreference = AppSharedPreference.getInstance(this);
        initView();
    }

    private void initView()
    {
        loginUserId =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.login_userid);
        loginPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.login_password);

        btnLogin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

        tvForgetPassword=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_forgetpassword);

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvForgetPassword.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_login:

            checkValidation();
            break;

        case R.id.tv_forgetpassword:

            startActivity(new Intent(this,ForgetPasswordActivity.class));
            break;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void callLoginApi() {
        String string_loginUserId = loginUserId.getText().toString();
        String string_loginPassword = loginPassword.getText().toString();

        Map<String, String> param = null;
        try {
            param = new HashMap<String, String>();
            param.put("username", string_loginUserId);
            param.put("trpass", string_loginPassword);
            param.put("action", "LOGIN");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String jobjstr = param.toString();
        Log.e("LOGINREQUESTTTTTTT", jobjstr);
        if (jobjstr != null) {
            AllInOneAsyncTask asyncTask = new AllInOneAsyncTask(
                    LoginActivity.this);
            asyncTask.setServiceResultListener(this);
            asyncTask.setServiceType(Constants.SERVICE_TYPE_GET_PROFILE);
            asyncTask.execute(param);
        }
    }

    private void checkValidation()
    {
        String string_loginUserId = loginUserId.getText().toString();
        String string_loginPassword = loginPassword.getText().toString();

        if(!string_loginUserId.matches(""))
        {
            if(string_loginPassword.length()>=6)
            {
                callLoginApi();
            }
            else
            {
                AppUtil.DefaultPopup(this, getResources().getString(R.string.wrong_password));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            AppUtil.DefaultPopup(this,getResources().getString(R.string.wrong_usrId));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(String resultData, int requestType) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (requestType == Constants.SERVICE_TYPE_GET_PROFILE) {
            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(resultData);
                String status = obj.getString("Status");
                String message = obj.getString("Message");
                if (status.equals("1")) {
                    String string_loginUserId = loginUserId.getText().toString();
                    String string_loginPassword = loginPassword.getText().toString();

                    String balance = obj.getString("Balance");
                    String name = obj.getString("Name");
                    String mobile = obj.getString("Mobile");
                    String email = obj.getString("Email");

                    appSharedPreference.setBalance(balance);
                    appSharedPreference.setName(name);
                    appSharedPreference.setMobile(mobile);
                    appSharedPreference.setEmail(email);
                    appSharedPreference.setUserName(string_loginUserId);
                    appSharedPreference.setPassword(string_loginPassword);

                    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
                else {
                    AppUtil.DefaultPopup(this,message);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

activity_login.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_grayish_blue" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="LOGIN IN MY ACCOUNT"
        android:textColor="#F26341"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp">

    <EditText
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="@string/tx_user"
        style="@style/EditTextStyle"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
        android:id="@+id/login_userid" />

    <EditText
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="@string/tx_password"
        style="@style/EditTextStyle"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
        android:id="@+id/login_password"/>

    <Button
        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:text="@string/tx_login"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_forgetpassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/tx_forgotpassword"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

i get an exception.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.webzone.allbillpay, PID: 11361
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.webzone.allbillpay/com.webzone.allbillpay.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference
        at com.webzone.allbillpay.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:39)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Comment: Please post your xml code.

Comment: Post your activity_login.xml

Comment: in you manifest file where you have declared your activity, just add this tag `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.WithActionBar"`

Comment: thanks. this is working.
@AbrahamGharyali

Comment: @Prabal.PX, If that helps you, please accept my answer which I mentioned below, so that it can also help others :).

Answer (score 0):

The default theme for your application must be set with no actionbar so you are getting null on actionbar.

The shortest fix for that is in you manifest file where you have declared your activity tag, inside just add this property

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.WithActionBar"
```

Answer (score -1):

Your LoginActivity has a theme which doesnt have an actionbar. Check the theme mentioned in manifest.

As the activity has no actionbar,getActionBar() returns a null value. And

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.header)));
```

causes the crash

Do this

```
if(getActionBar() != null) {
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.header)));
}
```

or change the activity's theme

```
<activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
```

remove the `android:theme`

Answer (score -1):

Navigate to your Toolbar in xml file and replace with this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

This will change the toolbar color to colorAccent

Comment this portion in java file. The above xml file will do the trick.

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.header)));
```

Before the toolbar color change

[image]


After changing color in app_bar_main.xml , below is the toolbar
[image]

Theme used is

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: If somebody has to downvote , they need to give a good reason as well. The above stuff is a working code... If you think there is a better answer, print out that stuff rather than downvoting